# ASP.NET Core & EF > ModelState.IsValid is showing invalid on field that is not in my model

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0

I'm new at ASP.NET Core 8 in VS 2022. I have created two tables (models `QS_Server_Details` and `Applications`) and used the standard scaffolding task for crud.

The CRUD operations for `QS_Server_Details` work as expected with the database (SQL). However the operations for `Application` are not passing the `ModelState.IsValid` check, and keep showing an "invalid field" error that is not in my model. It looks to be the table name.

Please could you help and point me to the error?

Models below

[QS_Server_Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD5nl.png)

[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDWiM.png)

As you can see the application has a foreign key to `QS_Server_Details` entity.

Error message

[Debug Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZHbf.png)

I can insert into the database manually via SQL. So I know the PK/FK constraint looks like and only have 5 fields (`ID` is the PK and `QS_Server_DetailsID` is the FK)

[Database Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWjQs.png)

Please help

Comment: [DO NOT use images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your debug, the virtual property `QS_Server_Details` is needed, and the default CRUD won’t pass it, which caused the modelstate to be invalid. Since you are not intending to enable lazy loading, you can just avoid validating the property through `[ValidateNever]`.

```
Application.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace YourNamespace.Models
{
    [DisplayName("Application")]
    public class Application
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(36, ErrorMessage = "Must Be 36 chars", MinimumLength = 36), Required, DisplayName("Application Id")]
        public string QS_ApplicationId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Application Name")]
        public string QS_AppName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Script")]
        public string QS_Script { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("QS_Server_Details")]
        public int QS_Server_DetailsID { get; set; }
        //Avoid validating
        [ValidateNever]
        public virtual QS_Server_Details QS_Server_Details { get; set; }
        public Application(){}
    }
}
```

Debug

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the speedy pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using the EF convention like 'QS_Server_DetailsId',
you do not need to put in the public Application() at the bottom again.

As for the QS_Server_Details, Just add this

```
public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications {get; set;}
```

Again you do need to have public QS_Server_Details() at the bottom